# Aggregating results from linear model runs R

Tags: r, regression

Since regression modeling is often more "art" than science, I often find myself testing many iterations of a regression structure. What are some efficient ways to summarize the information from these multiple model runs in an attempt to find the "best" model? One approach I've used is to put all the models into a list and run `summary()` across that list, but I imagine there are more efficient ways to compare?

Sample code & models:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)

lm1 <- lm(weight ~ group)
lm2 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1)
lm3 <- lm(log(weight) ~ group - 1)

#Draw comparisions between models 1 - 3?

models <- list(lm1, lm2, lm3)

lapply(models, summary)
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like data dredging to me. Shouldn't the focus be on what you plausibly think is an appropriate model, what covariates, transformations etc *before* you start modelling. R doesn't know you did all that model fitting to find a good model.

Comment: @Gavin - I can see this getting horrendously off-topic very quickly, but the short answer is no, I am not advocating data dredging or finding spurious relationships between random variables in a dataset. Consider a regression model that includes income. Is it not reasonable to test transformations on income to see their impact on the model? Log of income, log of income in 10s of dollars, log of income in 100s...?Even if this is data dredging - a function / summary tool that can aggregate the output from many model runs would still be very helpful, no?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Plot them!](http://tables2graphs.com/doku.php?id=04_regression_coefficients)

http://svn.cluelessresearch.com/tables2graphs/longley.png

Or, if you must, use tables:
The [apsrtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apsrtable/index.html) package or the `mtable` function in the [memisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html) package.

Using `mtable`

```
 mtable123 <- mtable("Model 1"=lm1,"Model 2"=lm2,"Model 3"=lm3,
     summary.stats=c("sigma","R-squared","F","p","N"))

> mtable123

Calls:
Model 1: lm(formula = weight ~ group)
Model 2: lm(formula = weight ~ group - 1)
Model 3: lm(formula = log(weight) ~ group - 1)

=============================================
                 Model 1   Model 2   Model 3 
---------------------------------------------
(Intercept)      5.032***                    
                (0.220)                      
group: Trt/Ctl  -0.371                       
                (0.311)                      
group: Ctl                 5.032***  1.610***
                          (0.220)   (0.045)  
group: Trt                 4.661***  1.527***
                          (0.220)   (0.045)  
---------------------------------------------
sigma             0.696      0.696     0.143 
R-squared         0.073      0.982     0.993 
F                 1.419    485.051  1200.388 
p                 0.249      0.000     0.000 
N                20         20        20     
=============================================
```

> 

Comment: @Eduardo, +1, nice graph. It should be used with care though when the different transformation of dependent variable is used in different regressions.

Comment: mpiktas, that´s true in a table as well. Graphs just make it more compact, at the expense of precision.

Comment: @Eduardo can you please share the code for graphs?

Comment: @suncoolsu R code is available on the first link given in @Eduardo's response. He he, it's `grid`, not `lattice` :)

Comment: @Eduardo - Thanks for the detailed answer, I wasn't aware of `memisc` previously, looks like a very handy package to have in one's quiver!

Comment: Memisc has a bunch of not very much related but nonetheless very useful functions. I don't use it as often as I should.

Comment: @Chl .. Thanks .. for the humor. Eduardo, your website is great! Thank you for sharing awesome code :-) I hope I can do it in `lattice`. :D

Comment: @suncoolsu Let's go with a `lattice` implementation then :) It should not be too hard.

Comment: How would I plot just the intercept and unemployed?

Answer (score 12):

The following doesn't answer exactly the question. It may give you some ideas, though. It's something I recently did in order to assess the fit of several regression models using one to four independent variables (the dependent variable was in the first column of the df1 dataframe).

```
# create the combinations of the 4 independent variables
library(foreach)
xcomb <- foreach(i=1:4, .combine=c) %do% {combn(names(df1)[-1], i, simplify=FALSE) }

# create formulas
formlist <- lapply(xcomb, function(l) formula(paste(names(df1)[1], paste(l, collapse="+"), sep="~")))
```

The contents of as.character(formlist) was

```
 [1] "price ~ sqft"                     "price ~ age"                     
 [3] "price ~ feats"                    "price ~ tax"                     
 [5] "price ~ sqft + age"               "price ~ sqft + feats"            
 [7] "price ~ sqft + tax"               "price ~ age + feats"             
 [9] "price ~ age + tax"                "price ~ feats + tax"             
[11] "price ~ sqft + age + feats"       "price ~ sqft + age + tax"        
[13] "price ~ sqft + feats + tax"       "price ~ age + feats + tax"       
[15] "price ~ sqft + age + feats + tax"
```

Then I collected some useful indices

```
# R squared
models.r.sq <- sapply(formlist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$r.squared)
# adjusted R squared
models.adj.r.sq <- sapply(formlist, function(i) summary(lm(i))$adj.r.squared)
# MSEp
models.MSEp <- sapply(formlist, function(i) anova(lm(i))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',])

# Full model MSE
MSE <- anova(lm(formlist[[length(formlist)]]))['Mean Sq']['Residuals',]

# Mallow's Cp
models.Cp <- sapply(formlist, function(i) {
SSEp <- anova(lm(i))['Sum Sq']['Residuals',]
mod.mat <- model.matrix(lm(i))
n <- dim(mod.mat)[1]
p <- dim(mod.mat)[2]
c(p,SSEp / MSE - (n - 2*p))
})

df.model.eval <- data.frame(model=as.character(formlist), p=models.Cp[1,],
r.sq=models.r.sq, adj.r.sq=models.adj.r.sq, MSEp=models.MSEp, Cp=models.Cp[2,])
```

The final dataframe was

```
                      model p       r.sq   adj.r.sq      MSEp         Cp
1                price~sqft 2 0.71390776 0.71139818  42044.46  49.260620
2                 price~age 2 0.02847477 0.01352823 162541.84 292.462049
3               price~feats 2 0.17858447 0.17137907 120716.21 351.004441
4                 price~tax 2 0.76641940 0.76417343  35035.94  20.591913
5            price~sqft+age 3 0.80348960 0.79734865  33391.05  10.899307
6          price~sqft+feats 3 0.72245824 0.71754599  41148.82  46.441002
7            price~sqft+tax 3 0.79837622 0.79446120  30536.19   5.819766
8           price~age+feats 3 0.16146638 0.13526220 142483.62 245.803026
9             price~age+tax 3 0.77886989 0.77173666  37884.71  20.026075
10          price~feats+tax 3 0.76941242 0.76493500  34922.80  21.021060
11     price~sqft+age+feats 4 0.80454221 0.79523470  33739.36  12.514175
12       price~sqft+age+tax 4 0.82977846 0.82140691  29640.97   3.832692
13     price~sqft+feats+tax 4 0.80068220 0.79481991  30482.90   6.609502
14      price~age+feats+tax 4 0.79186713 0.78163109  36242.54  17.381201
15 price~sqft+age+feats+tax 5 0.83210849 0.82091573  29722.50   5.000000
```

Finally, a Cp plot (using library wle)

[image]