# Aggregating results from Arima runs R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, arima

/edit: To clarify: The mtable function from the [memisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html) package does exactly what I need, but unfortunately does not work with arima models.

Similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/aggregating-results-from-linear-model-runs-r): I have multiple Arima models, some of which I've also fit with dependent variables. I'd like an easy way to make a table/graph of the coefficients in each model, as well as summary statistics about each model.

Here is some example code:

```
sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)

ar1<-arima(sim,order=c(1,1,0))
ar2<-arima(sim,order=c(2,1,0))
ar3<-arima(sim,order=c(3,1,0))
ar4<-arima(sim,order=c(2,2,1))

#Try mtable
library(memisc)
mtable("Model 1"=ar1,"Model 2"=ar2,"Model 3"=ar3,"Model 4"=ar4)
#>Error in UseMethod("getSummary") : 
#  no applicable method for 'getSummary' applied to an object of class "Arima"

#Try  apsrtable
library(apsrtable)
apsrtable("Model 1"=ar1,"Model 2"=ar2,"Model 3"=ar3,"Model 4"=ar4)
#>Error in est/x$se : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: why do the approaches described in the question you mention not work for you?

Comment: @mpiktas - it looks like the OP tried the methods mentioned previously has has copied the corresponding errors in the code above.

Comment: @Chase, when I commented, there was no R code example.

Comment: @mpiktas - I blame the [R gremlins](http://theshoegame.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/gizmo-gremlins-picture.jpg)

Comment: @mpiktas - I added a code example that lists what I tried to do and the errors I got.  I hit the 3 methods discussed in the previous question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write a function called `getSummary.Arima` for use with the `memisc` package. Check out `getSummary.lm` for an example.

Comment: @Zach - did you happen to make any progress with writing the `getSummary.Arima` function? I'm taking a ts course this term and would be glad to lend a hand if needed. Let me know.

Comment: @Chase - I didn't ever start on this.  If you'd like to take a shot at it, I'd be glad to help out.